# Can't change culture in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, localization

I want to change culture to `ru-RU` to parse dates in `dd-mm-yyyy` format.
I tried to add culture to `Web.Config` and `Application_BeginRequest`, but it doesn't happens - in my controllers culture is still `en-US`

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="ru-RU" uiCulture="ru" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

and

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
}
```

Comment: Did you try in **Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute()** ?  Setting it like so: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU");

Comment: I suggest you to read [this article](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx) about handling localization in ASP.NET-MVC. You can find your answer in the paragraph about _Determining Culture_

Comment: Setting the culture in the `web.config` file will work fine. What makes yo think that the culture is still `en-US`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I check it in my controller's method `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`

Comment: Copied your `<globalization culture="ru-RU" uiCulture="ru" />` into my current project and `var c = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;` returns `ru-RU` for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try create a base class for your entire site (all others controllers will Inherits from this one) and put some piece of code like this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-Ru");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("ru-Ru");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
```

Hope it helps!